# How to add a non-breaking space after "ed. by" in BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, white-space

I tried this:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  byeditor={ed.~by\penalty10000},
}
```

but it didn't work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Any example to play with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using one of the standard styles, there are three different macros you need to change in addition to your string redefinition: `byeditor`, `byeditor+others`, and `byeditorx`. In these three macros we need to replace the delimeter between the `byeditor` string and the `editor` (which is normally `\addspace`) with a non-breaking space (`\addnbspace`).

Note that you may need to do something similar with the three analogous translator macros.

It's a bit hard to show this working, but try this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  byeditor = {ed\adddot\addnbspace by},
}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addnbspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addnbspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditorx}{%
  \ifnameundef{editora}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editora}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addnbspace}%
     \printnames[byeditora]{editora}%
     \newunit}%
  \ifnameundef{editorb}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editorb}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addnbspace}%
     \printnames[byeditorb]{editorb}%
     \newunit}%
  \ifnameundef{editorc}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editorc}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addnbspace}%
     \printnames[byeditorc]{editorc}%
     \newunit}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{aristotle:anima,gaonkar:in,salam}
\parbox{5cm}{%
  \printbibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: nobreak output]

For comparison, here is the output without the redefined string and macros:

[image: break output]